# Paying fees for missing return flight timeshare free trip

Tags: return-tickets

I recently received a promotional trip after attending a timeshare presentation. The trip is for 3 nights, and we are being told that the "only way" to extend is to pay their chosen travel agency to extend.

My question is this: if we were to miss the return flight, would the agency have any recourse in terms of punishing us for missing that flight? I've seen that they can find out you missed the flight by checking the PNR, but it's unclear to me how they can enforce that you MUST take a specific return flight.

Comment: "only way to extend" I would immediately think was related to the _accommodation_ rather than the _flight_

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing at all stopping you from not using the return ticket.  In fact, if you have a flight ticket in your name and you know the PNR (6-letter reservation code), you may be able to simply call up the airline and change your flights, although as @Doc points out this depends on the arrangement between the airline and the purchaser/agency.  If this is possible, you may be required to pay change fees (which may be substantial, since they would have bought the cheapest possible fixed ticket) and you will be on the hook for them.

You *will* almost certainly need to go through the designated agent if you want to stay longer at the accommodation they've arranged at the destination.  But if you're happy staying somewhere else, that's not a problem either.

As for whether the agency has any recourse, anybody can sue anybody for anything, but I don't see what possible grounds they would have or why they would even care.  You attended the presentation, you went on the trip, not using the return flight or making changes on your own does not involve them in any way and will cost them nothing at all, so they have no damages to sue for.

Comment: This would require the airline to take "Control" of the ticket.  Many airlines will simply not do this.  Others will, but will charge the customer a fee for doing it.  The airline has paid the travel agency a fee/commission to handle the booking, so any changes generally must be made through them.  This is doubly true for things like "bulk" bookings, which a timeshare incentive booking likely is.

Comment: @Doc TIL.  Updating answer.

Comment: In this case it's actual beneficial that the agency has booked the ticket. Technically its akin to hidden city ticketing and violates the terms and conditions of the airline. Since it's the last leg of the itinerary their recourse is limited and I doubt they would take action for a ticket like this.